# How to get a token mint address from a transaction signature in Solana web3

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js

How do get the token mint address from a transaction signature in Solana web3?

Here's an example.
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4y2zCnN1ciucLE6z91J7cQXz4skhCpoBJqhcecfuri5zp2NMSYejopTvGq2sYS9Ud5AkRirFkLXocZKdNfzWudG3?cluster=devnet

This is the transaction signature.
`4y2zCnN1ciucLE6z91J7cQXz4skhCpoBJqhcecfuri5zp2NMSYejopTvGq2sYS9Ud5AkRirFkLXocZKdNfzWudG3`

I want the token mint address so I can look up the metadata.
`DzAP4MvZNzV6zUrAW9wKXzDrpgRmEPa1QHhrSBEB823W`

I can't figure out how to get the token mint from the transaction signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could do that.

### Solution 1

You can check the instruction #5 i.e the **Candy Machine: Mint** instruction (code [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L37=)) the mint account is the account number 6 ([code](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L57=)) and the metadata account is the account number 5 ([code](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L54=))

In JS it would be something like:

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

async function getMint(tx: string) {
  const result = await connection.getTransaction(tx);

  const metadaIndex = result?.transaction.message.instructions[4].accounts[4];
  const mintIndex = result?.transaction.message.instructions[4].accounts[5];

  if (!metadaIndex || !mintIndex) {
    throw new Error("Account not found");
  }

  return {
    mint: result?.transaction.message.accountKeys[mintIndex],
    metadata: result?.transaction.message.accountKeys[metadaIndex],
  };
}

getMint(
  "4y2zCnN1ciucLE6z91J7cQXz4skhCpoBJqhcecfuri5zp2NMSYejopTvGq2sYS9Ud5AkRirFkLXocZKdNfzWudG3"
);
```

And it will return

```json
{
  mint: 'DzAP4MvZNzV6zUrAW9wKXzDrpgRmEPa1QHhrSBEB823W',
  metadata: '4YR5CeLEZCF7qVpvHQfYoL84gQQb6uj5sGbaAqP2Eqgj'
}
```

### Solution 2

Another solution would be to look at the instruction #4 i.e the **Token Program: Mint To** and extract the [first key](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/processor.rs#L523=)

In JS it would be

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

async function getMint(tx: string) {
  const result = await connection.getTransaction(tx);

  const mintIndex = result?.transaction.message.instructions[3].accounts[0];

  if (!mintIndex) {
    throw new Error("Account not found");
  }

  return {
    mint: result?.transaction.message.accountKeys[mintIndex],
  };
}

getMint(
  "4y2zCnN1ciucLE6z91J7cQXz4skhCpoBJqhcecfuri5zp2NMSYejopTvGq2sYS9Ud5AkRirFkLXocZKdNfzWudG3"
);
```

And it will return

```
{ mint: 'DzAP4MvZNzV6zUrAW9wKXzDrpgRmEPa1QHhrSBEB823W' }
```